# Javascript trying to get value of an element not working

Tags: javascript

My code:

```js
function $(selector){
    var self = {
        el:document.querySelector(selector),
        html:()=> self.el.innerHTML,
        on:(event, callback)=>{
            document.addEventListener(event, callback)
        },
        hide:()=> {
            self.el.style.display = 'none'
        },
        attr:(attr, value)=>{
            if(value == null){
                self.el.getAttribute(attr)
            }else{
            self.el.setAttribute(attr, value);
            }
        },
        setHTML:(code)=>{
            self.el.innerHTML = "";
            self.el.innerHTML = code;
        },
        createChld:(childElement, id, clss, innerHTML)=>{
            var el = document.createElement(childElement);
            el.setAttribute('id', id);
            el.setAttribute('class', clss);
            el.innerHTML = innerHTML;
            self.el.appendChild(el);
        },
        addClass:(clss)=>{
            self.el.classList.add(clss)
        },
        addId:(id)=>{
            self.el.id = id;
        },
        value:()=>{
            self.el.value;
        }
    }
    return self
}
```

When I try to use something like $('input').value() it doesn't work it just results to undefinded, I don't know why but I think it has something to do with self.el.value.
Thanks.

Comment: `document.querySelector(selector)` returns a list of HTML Elements, may be that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions need a return statement if they are wrapped with `{}`. Use:

```js
        value: ()=>{
            return self.el.value;
        }
```

Alternatively, you could not use curly brackets.

```js
        value: ()=>self.el.value;
```

Comment: thanks, it worked I guess it because the other methods change something like id = id but this just give a value.

Answer (score 0):

I had a familiar problem, in my case it was that I have linked the script before the HTML object. Check for yourself too